# How to click on button by onclick method?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, puppeteer

I am use puppeteer for get data from page. But all button on webpage have same type and class - only difference is onclick attribute. I need click on different button to open tray with information I need.

For example:

```
> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
> onclick="OpenTray(10002)">More</button>

> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
> onclick="OpenTray(10003)">More</button>

> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
> onclick="OpenTray(10004)">More</button>
```

So how I can tell puppeteer only click on button with onclick attribute for example `OpenTray(10002)`

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to achieve this with a slightly more complex selector:

```js
const button = await page.waitForSelector(`button[onclick="OpenTray(10004)"]`)
```

There are a lot of [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) you can use to match the values of the attributes e.g. contains, starts with, ends with.